# Windows Explorer not responding with a file. Not able to delete

Tags: windows-explorer

I have some issues with a Windows 2003 server. I replaced a disk in an RAID 5 array but the rebuild aborts because of a read error on another disk in the array. I fould out that there is a data file I can't access, as if I just try right-click on it Windows Explorer becomes unresponsive, and I must reboot the server.
I imagine the problem is with that file, but how can I just delete it?
Thanks

Comment: Is it hardware or software RAID ? It matters ! I would check the remaining disks for integrity ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to unlock the file using Unlocker:

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Answer (score 1):

1. Try deleting from cmd line
2. Run chkdsk /f /x which requires a reboot, then try deleting
3. Boot from a winPE disk such as [Ucdc4win](http://Ubcd4win.com) then delete from this